# Keep a stream open from a function to another

Tags: c++, file-io, stream

Is there any way to keep a stream (to read or write in a file) open from a function to another in C++?

Comment: Why do you need to do this? What is the problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: Just pass it to the function without closing...if this doesn't answer your question, please be more specific.

Comment: I'm starting to think there might be an `fstream` object made *in* the function.

Comment: I noticed the a stream is automatically closed at the end of a scope. 
Right now I also just tried to pass it by reference, I use it in my "File" class's method: `int File::sendErrorOpeningStream(std::string ifstream_ofstream, std::ofstream outputFile, char *wd)` 
  
  BUT I then come up with : _error C2664: 'File::sendErrorOpeningStream' : cannot convert parameter 2 from 'std::ostream' to 'std::ofstream'_

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can either create the stream outside of the functions and pass it as a parameter to the methods:

`void myFunction(ifstream &stream) {...}`

Later close the stream when you are done with it: `stream.close()`.

Or create the stream within the first function and return it to the calling method and then pass it to the second function.

Comment: "Creating" it in the first function will force you to create heap, since a stack object will run out of scope. I discourage that.

Comment: I use it in the method: `int File::sendErrorOpeningStream (std::string ifstream_ofstream, std::ofstream outputFile, char *wd)`  
  
                    
BUT I then come up with : _error C2664: 'File::sendErrorOpeningStream' : cannot convert parameter 2 from 'std::ostream' to 'std::ofstream'_

Comment: @RobinLen'hog: Streams are not copyable. So you can not pass them by value. You must pass by reference.

Comment: So should I write it this way? 
`int File::sendErrorOpeningStream (std::string ifstream_ofstream, std::ofstream outputFile&, char *wd)` ??

Answer (score 2):

Pass it by reference

```
void myFunction(ifstream &myStream)
```

Answer (score 1):

Make it global or pass it as an argument but ensure that if you pass it as an argument you past it by reference not by value! If you pass it by value the compiler will NOT complain and weird things start happening.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it will complain that you can't copy it. Other than that, the second option is much better.

Comment: @chris I haven't seen a compiler complain about it yet but you may be right. Nonetheless by reference is the way to go.

Comment: I get a `Use of deleted function...`. That's C++11-specific; I'm not sure how it is in 03 then.

Answer (score 1):

Since C++11 file stream got [move constructor (6)](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ifstream/basic_ifstream). You can use it to pass opened stream between functions. Consider the following code snippet:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

bool open_stream(const std::wstring& filepath, std::ifstream& stream)
{
  std::ifstream innerStream;
  innerStream.open(filepath.c_str(), std::ios::in | std::ios::binary);
  if (innerStream.is_open())
  {
    stream = std::move(innerStream); // <-- Opened stream state moved to 'stream' variable 
    return true;
  }
  return false;
}  // <-- innerStream is destructed, but opened stream state is preserved as it was moved to 'stream' variable
```

Consider the next code to illustrate the usage of `open_stream`:

```
int main()
{
  std::ifstream outerStream;
  std::wcout << L"outerStream is opened: " << outerStream.is_open() << std::endl; // <-- outerStream is opened: 0

  if (!open_stream(L"c:\\temp\\test_file.txt", outerStream))
  {
    return 1;
  }

  std::wcout << L"outerStream is opened: " << outerStream.is_open() << std::endl; // <-- outerStream is opened: 1 

  // outerStream is opened and ready for reading here

  return 0;
}
```